# IOS file association - default app to open certain file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Is there any way to make my application default to open certain file types(e.g from Mail app).  In this moment it is opened by Preview by default and the application is listed in the Open in.... Howeever, preview has nothing to do with this file type and this application is the only one, that can handle this file type.

So I would like to make my application default for this file type, so Preview will not open it by default. Some google search has revealed that in Mac OSX there is key like LSIsAppleDefaultForType, that can make app default, but I can't find any option for IOS...

Comment: Wait, are you asking about Mac OS X or iOS? Preview only exists on Mac OS X, not iOS.

Comment: iOS. It is Quick Look, sorry. I already managed to avoid file opening in Quick Look, but can't make app default file viewer. Additional Open in... menu pops up.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're asking about iOS? Quick Look is also only on Mac OS X, not iOS.

Comment: For illustration, [this](http://imgur.com/GJAbx) is a screenshot of Mac OS X, not iOS. Note Quick Look in the foreground and Preview in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to associate you app with the file types you want it to open.
You do this by adding some parameters to your Info.plist.

This post explains it:
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Comment: I have associated it, but i want to make my application default for this file type.

Comment: @OlgaDalton it is impossible to associate any filetype with your application by default in iOS for this moment